# Find a path or route in R

Tags: r

So here is a matrix A which shows if point 1 to 10 is connected with each other. 1 means they are connected and 0 means they are not. I would like to find out if there is a path from one point to the other. Let's say the start point is 1 and the end point is 3. The number of points involved in between doesn't matter. Points can be used repeatedly. I just want to know if 1 can reach 3. How can I do this?

From what we can see, one of the possible paths is 1-8-6-2-3. But how to do it with R? Thanks a lot. Any help is appreciated.

```
A 
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] 
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0 
 [2,]    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0     0 
 [3,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0 
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0 
 [5,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0 
 [6,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    0     0 
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     1 
 [8,]    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0     0 
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0 
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
```

Comment: nope, it's computer science. This adjacency matrix represents a graph. The question of the OP is called "shortest path problem".

Comment: By taking powers of the matrix until no more zeros disappear you obtain its *transitive closure.*  The $i,j$ entry is nonzero if and only if there exists a path from $i$ to $j$ (and its value counts the number of such paths of length equal to the power). Although this is inefficient for large matrices, it makes short work of small ones like that illustrated in the question.

Answer (score 7):

For this task I think that `igraph` will make your life easier

```
require(igraph)
dat <- read.table(text =
   '0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0     0
    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    0     0
    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     1
    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0     0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0', header = FALSE)

dat <- as.matrix(dat)
g <- graph.adjacency(dat, mode = "undirected")
get.shortest.paths(g, 1, 3)
## [[1]]
## [1] 1 8 6 2 3
```

If you just want to test if a path exist you can create your own function like this one

```
test_paths <- function(g, from, to, ...) {
    is.finite(c(shortest.paths(g, from,  to, ...)))
}

test_paths(g, 1, 9)
## [1] FALSE

test_paths(g, 1, 8)
## [1] TRUE
```

The idea behind this code is simple : `shortest.path` return `Inf` when there's no path between two node (and the path length when it exists) so we can just test whether the number returned is finite (`is.finite`).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by repetitive matrix multiplication, until the matrix stays the same:

```
# generate symetric matrix
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix(rbinom(100, 1, 0.2), nrow = 10)
m <- m * upper.tri(m)
m <- m + t(m)
m0 <- m
m0
```

Generated matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Now multiply, until its stabilized:

```
m <- m0 
while (TRUE) { 
    new_m <- sign(m + m %*% m)
    if (all(new_m == m))
        break;
    m <- new_m
}
m
```

The resultant matrix contains 1 if there is a path between those nodes:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    1     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    1     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    1     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    1     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```